# Flutter web: Disable focusability of TextFormField decorator

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a form with various `TextFormField`s side by side, each with an alert symbol in case the current text is invalid.

I do this by setting the property `decoration` with a `InputDecoration`:

```
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    isDense: true,
    counterStyle: TextStyle(
      height: double.minPositive,
    ),
    counterText: "",
    prefixIcon: _mandatoryFieldEmpty(name)
        ? IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.warning),
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {
              _hintDialog();
            },
          )
        : null,
    border: InputBorder.none,
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
  )
```

Unfortunately, if the user goes through the TextFormFields via the Tab-Button, the IconButton is also selected (so it basically needs to Tab-Button-presses to go from one text field to another, which is not a good user experience).

Is there a way to prevent the IconButton from being selected on Tab-Button press?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to use an `ExcludeFocus` Widget around `IconButton`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).